# SWIFT - helper class callback

Tags: function, swift, ios8, uialertview, uialertcontroller

In order to manage/shorten my code a little, I decided to try to create a helper class to manage all alerts.

The idea is that the helper class will create the alert. When the user presses the button, it will then send a callback to inform the code on the viewController which button is pressed. Then based on that I can fire different bits of code.

Currently the code I have manages to pop up the alert correctly, but I cannot get it to send the callback when the button is pressed.

here is my alert manager I created so far(still basic for simplicity):

```
var alertMgr: alertManager = alertManager()
class alertManager: NSObject {

func showAlert(titleText:String?, confirmText:String, cancelText:String, msgText:String, showCancel:Bool, showConfirm:Bool, style:UIAlertControllerStyle, viewController:UIViewController) -> Int? {


    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: titleText, message: msgText, preferredStyle: style)
    var myInt:Int!

    let actionLeft = UIAlertAction(title:cancelText, style: .Cancel) { action in

        println("0") //works when user presses cancel button
        myInt = 0
    }

    let actionRight = UIAlertAction(title:confirmText, style: .Default) { action in

        println("1") //works when user presses confirm button
        myInt = 1
    }

    alertController.addAction(actionLeft)
    alertController.addAction(actionRight)

    viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return myInt //does not return when button is pressed???
}  
}
```

In my code when I want to show an alert I use the following code:

```
        let titleTxt:String = "title txt goes here."
        let confirmTxt:String = "confirm"
        let cancelTxt:String = "cancel"
        let msgTxt:String = "some msg goes here."
        let showCancel:Bool = true
        let showConfirm:Bool = true
        let style:UIAlertControllerStyle = .ActionSheet

        let alert = alertMgr.showAlert(titleTxt, confirmText: confirmTxt, cancelText: cancelTxt, msgText: msgTxt, showCancel: showCancel, showConfirm: showConfirm, style:style, viewController: self)

        switch alert as Int! {
            case nil:
                println("nil value")
            case 0:
                println("cancel pressed")  //never gets fired. when button is pressed
            case 1:
                println("confirm pressed") //never gets fired. when button is pressed
            default:
                break
        }
```

The main problem is I cannot seem to get the call back to send the "myInt" value on button press. I have searched through pretty much all questions on here with [UIAlertController] and have not been able to find any hints that would push me in the right direction.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showAlert` returns the value of `myInt` before any of the given blocks gets a chance to be executed, the solution is to pass complete action-blocks as parameters of `showAlert`. In order to shorten the signature you can prepare a special type with text, block and flag values and make the function to process arrays of the objects of this type.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am not 100% sure I understand, can you please post a sample code to better help me understand? In the mean time I'll fiddle around and see if I can figure it out. Thanks :)

Comment: The blocks `actionLeft` and `actionRight` are invoked when user presses a button, but the function `showAlert` returns immediately - you can remove the return value as it is being useless. Instead you can use two parameters of type `UIAlertAction` to replace `actionLeft` and `actionRight` Note that there's a difference between blocks and closures, you can read more at the official documentation, anyway the approach is the same. You can take any standard method with a closure as an example of function/closure prototypes, e.g. `UIView 
+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
`

Comment: I think I might be a bit confused. So after I remove the return from :showAlert: and replace actionLeft/actionRight with two UIAlertAction params. Where does the callback happen to my VC?(so I can then fire the next bit of code, based on confirm/cancel) Feeling a little lost here. PS....I read up on little more on blocks/closures. but still not seeing this 100%

Comment: This is the best part: you create the blocks at your `vc` before you  call `showAlert`, inside of these blocks you can call any instance methods of the `vc` making it similar to delegate pattern or you can put most of the logic inside of these blocks as by being declared at the scope of your `vc` they have an easy access to its variables and methods.